# ''pixelatted'' ''griddy'' result from slope function (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, dem, slope, srtm

I use the SRTM downloader to download my DEM's, then it happens very often that when I create a slopemap there are weird artefacts in the slope map. Something I do before making the slopemap is reprojecting (warp) the data to the specific location I need. I already have tried different methods for capturing the slope and they always result in a slopemap with the weird grid structure [image: screencapture of the slopemap]

Comment: @Vincé thank you for linking this article, I just found out that this happens after reprojecting..... does this make sense?

Comment: @N_LLC yes, this makes sense. This is a common issue, if you use nearest neighbour for resampling.